# Itext7 Hebrew reverse issue

Tags: java, itext7

I have simple piece of code that writes a PDF sometime this PDF will contain RTL languages like Hebrew or Arabic.
I was able to manipulate the text and mirror it using Bidi (Ibm lib)
But the text is still running in reverse

[image: Here is the output comparison to the source]

In English it would be something like:

instead of:

```
The quick 
brown fox 
jumps over 
the lazy dog
```

It appears as:

```
the lazy dog
jumps over 
brown fox 
The quick
```

Complete code:

```
@Test
public void generatePdf()  {
    
      SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss");
        String dest = "c:\\temp\\" + formatter.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + ".pdf";
         String fontPath = "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\ARIALUNI.TTF";
         FontProgramFactory.registerFont(fontPath, "arialUnicode");
        OutputStream pdfFile = null;
        Document doc = null;
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        PdfFont PdfFont  = PdfFontFactory.createRegisteredFont("arialUnicode", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);      
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(output));
        pdfDoc.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);
        pdfDoc.addFont(PdfFont);
        doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
        doc.setBaseDirection(BaseDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

        String txt = "בתשרי נתן הדקל פרי שחום נחמד בחשוון ירד יורה ועל גגי רקד בכסלו נרקיס הופיע בטבת ברד ובשבט חמה הפציעה ליום אחד.  1234 באדר עלה ניחוח מן הפרדסים בניסן הונפו בכוח כל החרמשים";
        Bidi bidi = new Bidi();
        bidi.setPara(txt, Bidi.RTL, null);
        String mirrTxt = bidi.writeReordered(Bidi.DO_MIRRORING);
        Paragraph paragraph1 = new  Paragraph(mirrTxt)
                .setFont(PdfFont)
                .setFontSize(9)
                .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
                .setHeight(200)
                .setWidth(70);
        paragraph1.setBorder(new SolidBorder(3));
        doc.add(paragraph1);  
                    
        Paragraph paragraph2 = new  Paragraph(txt)
                .setFont(PdfFont)
                .setFontSize(9)
                .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
                .setHeight(200)
                .setWidth(70);
        paragraph2.setBorder(new SolidBorder(3));
        doc.add(paragraph2);  
        
        doc.close();
        doc.flush();
        pdfFile = new FileOutputStream(dest); 
        pdfFile.write(output.toByteArray()); 
        
        ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/C","explorer " + dest);
        b.start();
        
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {          
        try {pdfFile.close();} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Comment: iText 7 is capable of doing all the manipulations under the hood. No need to use Bidi algorithm. Just use pdfCalligraph add-on

Comment: pdfCalligraph is a paid add-on and this is for a software that will produce a single pdf in a every few month, so I am not sure this will get approved...

Comment: Generally in Hebrew, words will appear like dcba if expected abcd in viewer/editor, but if we split the characters into array and check, 'a' will be in position '0' in array.   May be didn't get your query. For your query, is the complete line is appearing reverse or only words appearing reverse ?

Comment: sentences appearing reverse  see example "the lazy dog" sentences  should be last but it comes first...

Answer (score 3):

The only solution that I have found with iText7 and IBM ICU4J without any other third party libraries is to first render the lines and then mirror them one by one. This requires a helper class `LineMirroring` and it's not precisely the most elegant solution, but will produce the output that you expect.

**Lines mirroring class**:

```
public class LineMirroring {

private final PageSize pageSize;
private final String fontName;
private final int fontSize;

public LineMirroring(PageSize pageSize, String fontName, int fontSize) {
    this.pageSize = pageSize;
    this.fontName = fontName;
    this.fontSize = fontSize;
}

public String mirrorParagraph(String input, int height, int width, Border border) {
    final StringBuilder mirrored = new StringBuilder();
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createRegisteredFont(fontName, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
        final PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(output);
        final PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
        pdfDoc.setDefaultPageSize(pageSize);
        pdfDoc.addFont(font);
        final Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
        doc.setBaseDirection(BaseDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        final LineTrackingParagraph paragraph = new LineTrackingParagraph(input);
        paragraph.setFont(font)
                .setFontSize(fontSize)
                .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT)
                .setHeight(height)
                .setWidth(width)
                .setBorder(border);
        LineTrackingParagraphRenderer renderer = new LineTrackingParagraphRenderer(paragraph);
        doc.add(paragraph);
        Bidi bidi;
        for (LineRenderer lr : paragraph.getWrittenLines()) {
            bidi = new Bidi(((TextRenderer) lr.getChildRenderers().get(0)).getText().toString(), Bidi.RTL);
            mirrored.append(bidi.writeReordered(Bidi.DO_MIRRORING));
        }
        doc.close();
        pdfDoc.close();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mirrored.toString();
}

private class LineTrackingParagraph extends Paragraph {

    private List<LineRenderer> lines;

    public LineTrackingParagraph(String text) {
        super(text);
    }

    public void addWrittenLines(List<LineRenderer> lines) {
        this.lines = lines;
    }

    public List<LineRenderer> getWrittenLines() {
        return lines;
    }

    @Override
    protected IRenderer makeNewRenderer() {
        return new LineTrackingParagraphRenderer(this);
    }
}

private class LineTrackingParagraphRenderer extends ParagraphRenderer {
    public LineTrackingParagraphRenderer(LineTrackingParagraph modelElement) {
        super(modelElement);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawChildren(DrawContext drawContext) {
        ((LineTrackingParagraph)modelElement).addWrittenLines(lines);
        super.drawChildren(drawContext);
    }

    @Override
    public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
        return new LineTrackingParagraphRenderer((LineTrackingParagraph) modelElement);
    }
}
```

}

**Minimal JUnit Test**:

```
public class Itext7HebrewTest {

@Test
public void generatePdf() {

    final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss");
    final String dest = "F:\\Temp\\" + formatter.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + ".pdf";
    final String fontPath = "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\ARIALUNI.TTF";
    final String fontName = "arialUnicode";
    FontProgramFactory.registerFont(fontPath, "arialUnicode");

    try (ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        PdfFont arial = PdfFontFactory.createRegisteredFont(fontName, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);

        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(output));
        pdfDoc.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);
        pdfDoc.addFont(arial);
        LineMirroring mirroring = new LineMirroring(pdfDoc.getDefaultPageSize(), fontName,9);

        Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
        doc.setBaseDirection(BaseDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

        final String txt = "בתשרי נתן הדקל פרי שחום נחמד בחשוון ירד יורה ועל גגי רקד בכסלו נרקיס הופיע בטבת ברד ובשבט חמה הפציעה ליום אחד.  1234 באדר עלה ניחוח מן הפרדסים בניסן הונפו בכוח כל החרמשים";

        final int height = 200;
        final int width = 70;
        final Border border = new SolidBorder(3);

        Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph(mirroring.mirrorParagraph(txt, height, width, border));
        paragraph1.setFont(arial)
                .setFontSize(9)
                .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT)
                .setHeight(height)
                .setWidth(width)
                .setBorder(border);
        doc.add(paragraph1);

        doc.close();
        doc.flush();
        try (FileOutputStream pdfFile = new FileOutputStream(dest)) {
            pdfFile.write(output.toByteArray());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for this, it generates wrong output, see here (your output is on the left)     https://ibb.co/fMnB3sq